# Apache not loading the appropriate page

Tags: debian, apache-http-server

I've recently setup a web server on my debian machine. Overall, everything is working wonderfully with one exception.
When I'm joining the address without specifying any file, it keeps loading up the default page (It works !) instead of my own index.html file.
If I specify a file however (like my phpinfo page or my index.html for example) it loads it just fine.

It does the same thing for the two virtual hosts I've created.

I'm quite sure I forgot to set something in a conf file somewhere, but I must say that I'm running out of idea.

Could anyone shed some light on how I could fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that Apache returns content of a certainly named file for a directory URL you must specify for which files the web server should look using the directive [`DirectoryIndex`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex). It could look like:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

In Debian this directive is in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` on the server configuration level by default. It could be further overridden on the virtual serve and directory level.